# Integration testing framework for websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, integration-testing, java-ee-6, websphere-8, jboss-arquillian

We are using websphere application server 8.5 for our enterprise applications.

I want to know is there any integration testing framework other than arquillian?

I tried running with arquillian with embedded and remote. Because embedded does not provide support for CDI we don't want to use it. And with remote we are not able to start our tests because of some security issue. Even if we try to solve that we cannot use @PersistenceContext or @Resource etc.

So I would like to know if there is any integration testing framework exclusively for websphere.

Thank you

P.S.
I think I misunderstood @PersistenceContext and @Resource. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I can use @PersistenceContext or @Resource in my actual application but not in my arquillian classes. Am I right? Earlier I thought I cannot use these anywhere in my code.

Secondly, as a quick test, I tried disabling administration security on WAS and the test case ran successfully.

Comment: For the security  issue you may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240653/arquillian-tests-stop-working-after-enabling-websphere-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know is there any integration testing framework other than arquillian?

Currently there are not any good Java EE test alternatives to Arquillian that I know of.  However, you can make a decent test framework using some very basic ant scripting and junit. 
([See this answer for testing in Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529835/java-ee-7-portable-solution-for-integration-and-unit-testing/34531872#34531872) for an example implementation)

> I think I misunderstood @PersistenceContext and @Resource. Please correct me if I am wrong.
>
> I can use @PersistenceContext or @Resource in my actual application but not in my arquillian classes. Am I right? Earlier I thought I cannot use these anywhere in my code.

If you're going to use `@PersistenceContext` or `@Resource` in a class, that class should be container managed (i.e. deployed in an application as part of an ear/war/ejb module)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

> Secondly, as a quick test, I tried disabling administration security
>   on WAS and the test case ran successfully

For secured server you need to add username/password and ssl config. For further information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240653/arquillian-tests-stop-working-after-enabling-websphere-security).

> Because embedded does not provide support for CDI we don't want to use
>   it.

That is actually not true. Embedded containers do support CDI and according to the [arquillian blog](http://arquillian.org/blog/2012/04/13/the-danger-of-embedded-containers/) CDI is one of the few reasons to use them... Update: On a 2nd look you are right as shown [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/WAS+V8.0+-+Embedded). The blog is probably talking about all the other containers...

> What is not supported by embedded containers?

Remote interfaces are not supported in the embeddable container.

In any way the above quoted [article](http://arquillian.org/blog/2012/04/13/the-danger-of-embedded-containers/) provides a good starting point when to use which container type.